# Moving one item on navigation's bar on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navigationbar

I can not find a way to move my navigation's last item (from the left) to the right side of the bar with Bootstrap styling

There are bunch of solutions, how to move all items to the right, but I need only my dropdown menu on the right side of the bar.

How can I do that, using only Bootstrap CSS classes?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        My account
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does changing `<li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right">` to `<li class="nav-item dropdown navbar-right float-right">` get what you want?

Comment: We can't solve it just with HTML. Please, upload the CSS or a live version

Comment: add some css code

Comment: using bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the `navs`, all left `navs` in one and right `navs` in another which will have class `navbar-right`.

Try this HTML structure:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            My account
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

> For results, Run code snippet in Expanded view.

Comment: If this resolved your issue and you find it most useful, Please accept it as Most useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this only if you are using bootstrap 4

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        My account
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```